# When retrieving documents from a cloudant database via the web interface, what order do they arrive?

Tags: couchdb, ibm-cloud, cloudant, ibm-watson

I want to retrieve a large collection of documents from Cloudant via the Web interface, with no sort directive, in 200-document pages (using bookmarks).  If I retrieve all of the pages, then retrieve them all again, will the documents in the two collections be in the same order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for [views](https://docs.cloudant.com/using_views.html), native UTF-8 sorting is applied to the key defined in the view function.

for [search indexes](https://cloudant.com/for-developers/search/), the default sort order is by relevance with the highest scoring matches first.

without making any changes that would impact the default sort order, subsequent retrievals should be in the same order.